# Bxslider only slides once on safari 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, bxslider

I have noticed that following a safari update (8.0.6), my BXslider now only lets you slide along one slide before not responding to any further attempts to navigate through the slider.

I have a pretty simple configuration (see below) with a custom CSS file. The example slider can be found [here](http://davidharkin.com/Ines/criticalanalysis.html)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
          $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
             mode: 'vertical',
             captions: false,
             infiniteLoop:false       
             });
        });
```

Has anyone else encountered their sliders no longer working on the new safari and discovered a workaround/fix?